# Missing SherlockActionBar dropdownmenu on phone, works on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, actionbarsherlock

I added the SherlockActionBar to my project, added a few menu items and it works fine in the emulator (4.0.3), but it does not work on my phone (Galaxy S3);  it just doesn't show up.

I'm targeting 15 with a minimum sdk version of 9 in my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/dimmiicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar" >
```

Code is rather straightforward, but perhaps i'm missing something.  Relevant bits...

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;


public class Launcher extends SherlockFragmentActivity  implements  OnUserAuthenticatedListener, OnDialogChatterListener, OnAnimationCompleteListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);

    final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    ab.setCustomView(R.layout.title_bar);

    ab.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.titlebarbackground));
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTitle1);  
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "caviar_dreams_bold.ttf");
    txt.setTypeface(font);
    TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTitle2);  
    Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "caviardreams.ttf");
    txt2.setTypeface(font2); 
}  
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.commonmenus, menu);
    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:

        return false;
    case R.id.search_for_product:
        performProductReview(findViewById(android.R.id.content));
        return true;
    case R.id.search_for_business:
        performCompanyReview(findViewById(android.R.id.content));
        return true;
    case R.id.search_for_service:
        performServiceReview(findViewById(android.R.id.content));
        return true;
    case R.id.search_for_person:
        performPersonReview(findViewById(android.R.id.content));
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And the commonmenus.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>
<item android:id="@+id/search_for_product" android:showAsAction="never" android:orderInCategory="10" android:title="@string/menu_search_for_product"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/search_for_business" android:showAsAction="never" android:orderInCategory="11" android:title="@string/menu_search_for_business"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/search_for_service" android:showAsAction="never" android:orderInCategory="12" android:title="@string/menu_review_service"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/search_for_person" android:showAsAction="never" android:orderInCategory="14" android:title="@string/menu_review_person"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/view_my_reviews" android:showAsAction="never" android:orderInCategory="15" android:title="@string/menu_view_my_reviews"></item>

</menu>
```

I'm using the sherlock actionbar to customize the title using some custom font's and that is working on the emulator AND the phone, but the menu only shows up on the emulator.  I did try it with the custom font code commented out and it made no difference.

Just so I'm clear:  the 3 menu dots don't even show up.

After spending a couple of hours searching and looking for a clue, I'm at a loss.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: The 3 dots (overflow menu) aren't supposed to show up, since the S3 has a dedicated menu button.

Comment: New phone... didn't know that so thank you.  Is there a way to make it show up?  I see it on other applications.

Comment: ActionBarSherlock *did* have a force overflow theme a few versions back. However I'd recommend keeping this as is; the overflow menu should only be seen on devices without a dedicated menu key.

Comment: Uggg.   I really don't like that very much.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For devices with Android Honeycomb+ `ActionBarSherlock` will use stock `ActionBar` features to work with, which means you're left with official ActionBar, which only puts the legacy menu button in very specific scenarios, see here:
http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

Under "Action overflow button for legacy apps":

> If your app runs on a device without a dedicated Menu button, the
>   system decides whether to add the action overflow to the navigation
>   bar based on which API levels you declare to support in the 
>   manifest element. The logic boils down to:
>
> If you set either minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion to 11 or higher,
>   the system will not add the legacy overflow button.
>
> Otherwise, the system will add the legacy overflow button when running
>   on Android 3.0 or higher.
>
> The only exception is that if you set minSdkVersion to 10 or lower,
>   set targetSdkVersion to 11, 12, or 13, and you do not use ActionBar,
>   the system will add the legacy overflow button when running your app
>   on a handset with Android 4.0 or higher.

Comment: @JakeWharton switched to iOS recently, short memory... :)